# Xcode Continuous Integration bot fails after Git force push

Tags: xcode, git, continuous-integration, osx-server

We have an Xcode CI bot setup to poll our git repository for new commits and build accordingly. Generally it runs fine. However after forced pushes (I know) the bot will fail and never build correctly again. The solution has been to delete the bot and start over (and admonish ourselves for force-pushing).

Within Xcode build logs there is no error, hitting the console we can only confirm what the problem is (see the last log)...

```
Jan 28 08:15:51 macmini.local xcsbuildd[80853]: [CSBotSCMAction gitCloneRepositoryAtURL:branch:destinationPath:createDirectoryNamed:completionBlock:] : https://github.com/XXXXXXXX/iOS.git
Jan 28 08:15:51 macmini.local xcsbuildd[80853]: newRepoURL: https://github.com/XXXXXXXX/iOS.git
    "https:\/\/githubuserformacmini@github.com\/XXXXXXXX\/iOS.git",
    "https_github_com_XXXXXXXX_iOS_git"
  "launchCommand" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/usr\/bin\/git clone https:\/\/githubuserformacmini@github.com\/XXXXXXXX\/iOS.git --recursive --verbose --progress https_github_com_XXXXXXXX_iOS_git",
  "launchPath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/usr\/bin\/git",
    "GIT_ASKPASS" : "\/Applications\/Server.app\/Contents\/ServerRoot\/usr\/libexec\/xcs_ssh_auth_agent",
Jan 28 08:18:29 macmini.local xcsbuildd[80853]: Obtaining the HEAD hash at: /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/BotRun-187dbc1a-dae2-4ddc-a75b-75831de7ff09.bundle/tmp/https_github_com_XXXXXXXX_iOS_git
Jan 28 08:18:29 macmini.local xcsbuildd[80853]: [CSBotSCMAction gitHeadHashesRepositoryAtPath:branch:completionBlock:] : /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/BotRun-187dbc1a-dae2-4ddc-a75b-75831de7ff09.bundle/tmp/https_github_com_XXXXXXXX_iOS_git
Jan 28 08:18:29 macmini.local xcsbuildd[80853]: newRepoURL: file:///Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/BotRun-187dbc1a-dae2-4ddc-a75b-75831de7ff09.bundle/tmp/https_github_com_XXXXXXXX_iOS_git/
  "launchCommand" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/usr\/bin\/git show-ref --heads",
  "launchPath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/usr\/bin\/git",
  "currentDirectoryPath" : "\/Library\/Server\/Xcode\/Data\/BotRuns\/BotRun-187dbc1a-dae2-4ddc-a75b-75831de7ff09.bundle\/tmp\/https_github_com_XXXXXXXX_iOS_git",
  "launchCommand" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/usr\/bin\/git checkout release",
  "launchPath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/usr\/bin\/git",
    "GIT_ASKPASS" : "\/Applications\/Server.app\/Contents\/ServerRoot\/usr\/libexec\/xcs_ssh_auth_agent",
  "currentDirectoryPath" : "\/Library\/Server\/Xcode\/Data\/BotRuns\/BotRun-187dbc1a-dae2-4ddc-a75b-75831de7ff09.bundle\/tmp\/https_github_com_XXXXXXXX_iOS_git",
Jan 28 08:18:29 macmini.local xcsbuildd[80853]: [CSBotSCMAction gitHeadHashesRepositoryAtPath:branch:completionBlock:] : https://github.com/XXXXXXXX/iOS.git
Jan 28 08:18:29 macmini.local xcsbuildd[80853]: newRepoURL: https://github.com/XXXXXXXX/iOS.git
    "https:\/\/githubuserformacmini@github.com\/XXXXXXXX\/iOS.git"
  "launchCommand" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/usr\/bin\/git ls-remote --heads https:\/\/githubuserformacmini@github.com\/XXXXXXXX\/iOS.git",
  "launchPath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/usr\/bin\/git",
    "GIT_ASKPASS" : "\/Applications\/Server.app\/Contents\/ServerRoot\/usr\/libexec\/xcs_ssh_auth_agent",
Jan 28 08:18:30 macmini.local xcsbuildd[80853]: [CSBotSCMAction gitCommitSummaryForRepositoryURL:betweenHashIdentifier:andHashIdentifier:completionBlock:] : /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/BotRun-187dbc1a-dae2-4ddc-a75b-75831de7ff09.bundle/tmp/https_github_com_XXXXXXXX_iOS_git
  "launchCommand" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/usr\/bin\/git log --no-color --name-status --format=fuller --date=iso e478616e4b3915846f7938fec24e8dc12cdae52a..f2c1b24a6b801ed9f7e60dce60add1851618da64",
  "launchPath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/usr\/bin\/git",
    "GIT_ASKPASS" : "\/Applications\/Server.app\/Contents\/ServerRoot\/usr\/libexec\/xcs_ssh_auth_agent",
  "currentDirectoryPath" : "\/Library\/Server\/Xcode\/Data\/BotRuns\/BotRun-187dbc1a-dae2-4ddc-a75b-75831de7ff09.bundle\/tmp\/https_github_com_XXXXXXXX_iOS_git",
Jan 28 08:18:30 macmini.local xcsbuildd[80853]: [XCSCheckoutOperation.m:1033 7d02a310 +168ms] Error getting Git commit log in range e478616e4b3915846f7938fec24e8dc12cdae52a:f2c1b24a6b801ed9f7e60dce60add1851618da64 <stderr>= fatal: Invalid revision range e478616e4b3915846f7938fec24e8dc12cdae52a..f2c1b24a6b801ed9f7e60dce60add1851618da64
Jan 28 08:18:30 macmini.local xcsbuildd[80853]: [XCSCheckoutOperation.m:610 7d02a310 +0ms] Failed to get Git commit history for repo with error Error Domain=CSBotSCMAction Code=-1000 "fatal: Invalid revision range e478616e4b3915846f7938fec24e8dc12cdae52a..f2c1b24a6b801ed9f7e60dce60add1851618da64
```

I can see...

```
git log --no-color --name-status --format=fuller --date=iso e478616e4b3915846f7938fec24e8dc12cdae52a..f2c1b24a6b801ed9f7e60dce60add1851618da64
```

...coming from the integration. e478616e4b3915846f7938fec24e8dc12cdae52a is the commit that was removed (I assume) when I forced in f2c1b24a6b801ed9f7e60dce60add1851618da64. I don't know where the bot is keeping around that information. I tried deleting everything out of /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns and that didn't work. I figured maybe it was pulling the last hash from /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Latest, nope. I also dug around a ton of the other directories in /Library/Server/Xcode without seeing anything.

It would be nice if Xcode's CI approach gave us any control over the git workflow. There's a ludicrously few amount of configuration options. Maybe delete is the only way to go.

Comment: `Git` gets this information by running the `post-receive` hook. If you can post the `post-receive` hook code then perhaps someone can help.

Comment: Unfortunately everything that would happen in a post-receive hook is compiled and locked away in what some application under the class CSBotSCMAction (at least that's what I can gather from the logs). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like someone removed a commit that was already pushed to a remote. Most CI servers detect changes in the repository with this basic workflow:

1. Fetch from remote
2. Do a git log or diff where the starting commit is the current HEAD of a cloned repository, and the end commit is the current HEAD of the remote branch the cloned repo is tracking

If the HEAD of the current checked out branch is removed in the remote repository, Git will probably fail.

You might be able to go to the directory where the CI build has the Git repository checked out and do:

```
git reset --hard origin/branch_name
```

This will bring your local and remote branches back in to parity. Then you'll probably need to kick off a manual build.

The *real* answer is to not alter Git's commit history when those commits have already been pushed to a remote.

Comment: Hi Greg, that's definitely what it is. And by "most CI servers" you need to remember it's Apple and they probably have their own approach for better and definitely for worse in this case. The location of the repository is also obscured and behind several locked directories. There's enough warning signs telling me I probably shouldn't be in there.

Comment: I understand. Fair enough :)

Comment: @rob5408, in all fairness, there are permissions to ensure you do not go in there all willy nilly. It does not mean you should not at the very least access them. Going into those directories may give you insight into this issue and others.